# CouchDB Count Reduce with timestamp filtering

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Let's say I have documents like so:

```
{ 
  _id: "a98798978s978dd98d", 
  type: "signature", 
  uid: "u12345", 
  category: "cat_1", 
  timestamp: UNIX_TIMESTAMP 
}
```

My goal is to be able to count all `signature`'s created by a certain `uid` but being able to filter by `timestamp`

Thanks to **[Alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5236185/alexis-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9)**, I've gotten to this far with a reduce _count function:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "signature") {
    emit([doc.uid, doc.timestamp], 1);
  }
}
```

With the following queries:

```
start_key=[null,lowerTimestamp]
end_key=[{},higherTimestamp]
reduce=true
group_level=1
```

Response:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [ "u11111" ],
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "key": [ "u12345" ],
      "value": 26
    }
  ]
}
```

It counts the `uid` correctly but the filter doesn't work properly. At first I thought it might be a CouchDB 2.2 bug, but I tried on Cloudant and I got the same response.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get this to work with being ale to filter timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

When using compound keys in MapReduce (i.e. the key is an array of things), you cannot query a range of keys with a "leading" array element missing. i.e. you can query a range of uuids and get the results ordered by timestamp, but your use-case is the other way round - you want to query uuids by time.

I'd be tempted to put time first in the array, but unix timestamps are not so good for grouping ;). I don't known the ins and outs of your application but if you were to index a *date* instead of a timestamp like so:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "signature") {
    var date = new Date(doc.timestamp)
    var datestr = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    emit([datestr, doc.uuid], 1);
  }
}
```

This would allow you to query a range of dates (to the resolution of a whole day):

```
?startkey=["2018-01-01"]&endkey=["2018-02-01"]&group_level=2
```

albeit with your uuids grouped by day.

Comment: Wow, what an ingenious idea to turn it into a date. Thanks for this. This is pretty awesome if I needed it for a specific day but the start and end keys would most likely be by month or year. Just doesn't seem possible without sending a query post with all the UID's I want.